# How to edit specific NSDictionary in plist files?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, nsdictionary

I have 20 Dictionary in plist file. I need to edit a specific Dictionary with their name but really didn't have any idea about how to do that.
I need to get values and make changes to SearchCountry Dictionary.

How to edit Specific dictionary values?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a sub-dictionary like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *plist = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistFilename];
NSMutableDictionary *searchCountry = [plist objectForKey:@"SearchCountry"];
```

Change one of it's values like this:

```
 [searchCountry setValue:@"Cleveland" forKey:@"searchcity"];
```

Save it like this:

```
BOOL success = [plist writeToFile:plistFilename atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [NSPorpertyListSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for complex iteration on the property list.

Otherwise you might have tried to access the particular dictionary using the following code

```
NSString*  plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourPList" 
                                                     ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary* plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath]; 
// plistDict contains all the dictionaries inside it now, you could try to access the particular inside the plistDict

id *searchKey = [plistDict objectForKey:@"SearchCountry"]; 
//OR
NSString* searchKeys = [plistDict valueForKeyPath:@"SearchCountry"];
```